# i encountered error ORA-01422 when executing the plsql query

Tags: oracle

> i encountered error  ORA-01422 when executing the plsql query below

```
Declare
    X NUMBER ;
    Bonus number; 
    begin 
    select acy_opening_bal into x from sttm_cust_account where branch_code ='000';
    bonus:= x+2000;
     dbms_output.put_line('bonus is: '|| bonus);
     end; 
    /
```

Comment: If you see the error, it'll tell you exactly what the problem is. Your select query return multiple rows and the x variable can hold only one value and hence the error. If you want any one acy_opening_bal, from the given result, you can add a `and rownum = 1` in the where clause. You may want max or min of the column, in case of which use the max and min (duh!) functions

Comment: Full error is: `ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows`. If your current tool does not display this information, I suggest you find another one.

Answer (score 0):

### try this:

```
Declare
    X NUMBER ;
    Bonus number; 
    begin 
    select distinct first_value(acy_opening_bal) over (partition by branch_code  ORDER BY acy_opening_bal ASC) into x from sttm_cust_account where branch_code ='000';
    bonus:= x+2000;
     dbms_output.put_line('bonus is: '|| bonus);
     end; 
    /
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply but what i aim to active is to give bonus of 2000 to all account in branch 000, but with the modifications you sent i have an output of sum of all the values in the branch. is way to achieve such with plsql??

i am new to plsql , and if you have any materials to help kindly share with me on easyty2008@gmail.com

Thank You

Comment: ...so why don't you use simple update, as in: update sttm_cust_account set acy_opening_bal = nvl(acy_opening_bal, 0) + 2000 where branch_code = '000'; ? If you really want to go through all rows with the branch code '000' and display something, but do not wish to actually update anything (?), than use for loop.